# How to validate Hive HQL syntax using pre-commit?

Tags: git, hive, hiveql, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

Is there a hook to validate HiveQL statements for errors like basic syntax mistakes? I'd like to check statements before commit to git repository.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good questions and an old problem in SQL world. For hive options are limited. You have two options - first one is low effort but not full proof, second one is full proof but need lot of work.

1. You can use `explain sql_statement;` for `insert/update/delete/select` type SQL. But this will not guarantee that your DML statement will not fail while changing data. There may be data type, length mismatch. So this option is not full proof but it can be used with minimum effort.
2. You can create sandbox environment/schema and run scripts there. You have to mimic your prod environment and setup tables, schemas there. Full proof option but work is more. You can create some kind of script to synch up the metadata with prod env.